# The db2prereqcheck utility was unable to determine the Linux distribution level

Tags: kernel, version, db2

I am trying to check prerequisites before installing IBM db2. I got this error

```
DBT3505E  The db2prereqcheck utility was unable to determine the Linux distribution level. %
```

I'm using XeroLinux (newbee)

After some research I stumbled across this
[solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2prereqcheck-fails-checking-linux-distribution#:%7E:text=There%20are%20several%20reasons%20why,file%20called%20%2Fetc%2Fissue.)

My `/etc/issue` has this line only:

[image: etc/issue]

My problem is how to edit this `/etc/issue` file in order for db2 to detect the kernel version.

Comment: I've this in /etc/issue `Kernel \r on an \m` and uname -r & uname -m provides kernel version & Architecture. On CentOS or AWS Linux